# Await promise in an rxjs obervable pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, token

When the access token expires, the backend return 401. I need to fetch a new token and then resend the failed request.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  req = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer s' + this.authService.authToken
    }
  });
   return next.handle(req);
```

I tried to use pipe as follows:

```
 return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError( async (err) => {
        if(err.status == 401){
          // Regenrate token. regenerateToken function is a promise
          await this.authenticationService.regenerateToken()
          //resend request
          return next.handle(req);
        }
      })
    );
```

but the issue is the catchError should return an observable of HttpEvent, and since the function that generates a new token is a promise, the **async** catchError function doesn't return an observable of HttpEven.

How can I generate a new token on 401, then resend the failed request when my generating token function is an async function?

Comment: have a look over these rxjs operators: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retry and https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retryWhen

Comment: one more thing .. I would rename `regenerateToken` to something like `login` or `getToken` since the token is not generated on the frontend, but on the backend. Just for the sake of clean & clear code.

Comment: yes, Im also having issues when I make it async

Comment: also, have you noticed the 's' character in the authorization header ? maybe that's the reason you are getting 401 from the backend. It may have to be 'Bearer ' + this.authService.authToken . Or did you do that just to trigger the 401 for testing purposes ?

Comment: oh thanks, ya its for testing purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the Promise into an Observable (using `from()` function) and then chain it with the next request:

```
catchError( async (err) => {
  if (err.status == 401){
    // Regenrate token. regenerateToken function is a promise
    return from(this.authenticationService.regenerateToken())
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => next.handle(req))
      )
  }
})
```

Comment: Im getting this now Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'

Comment: it worked, I just had to remove the async. Basically its an observable now anyhow no need for the async to await. Thanks!!